# still have the service invoked too many times even after removing the triggers

Tags: google-apps-script

I have made different scripts using reading emails coming in a particular label and making a google sheet out of the data in it (using triggers). It was already working when some time ago I began to get the "service invoked too many times" email (but the scripts still would work).

Currently, I am trying trying to debug the script again but I couldn't even get the script to run. I have already removed all of the triggers so it shouldn't be running but still get the error when trying it the next day.

My suspicion is that this is caused by another similar script that I also did. But since then I already passed on the ownership to another person and even deleted myself the notifications that were still coming into my email.

I still have the old emails and still have access to "modifying the triggers" but wouldn't want to change it there since it is not mine anymore.

Is there a place to see a log of my current errors in google apps script? or how do I get my account disassociated with that script?

Thanks,
Carlo

Answer (score 0):

If you can still see the triggers then they are still firing from your account. You cannot view triggers owned by other accounts.

If you created a doc and shared it with someone else then you need to delete the triggers and have the other user create them using their account or write a scrit that will create the trigger for them.

You should be able to look at what projects are making the calls here [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Comment: Sorry I missed this. I did delete myself from getting the notifications, but if I go to old emails I still can still edit the triggers if I wanted to. Many thanks.